# Trouble with AND operator on Eloquent Raw query MySQL JSON

Tags: mysql, json, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to figure out the correct syntax to add an AND operator to the following Eloquent Raw query in which I am querying a MySQL (5.7.9) table's JSON field.  In doing so, I would like to be able to have case insensitivity capabilities.

After doing initial research as to how to achieve this, I have my code working in a basic way like this:

```
$users = User::whereRaw('lower(info_json->"$.full_name") like lower(?)', ["%{$user_name}%"])
```

*But my goal is to add an **AND** operator to narrow down my results further with a non-JSON varchar column.*

I have tried this (and other variations without success):

```
$users = User::whereRaw('lower(info_json->"$.full_name") like lower(?)', 'and user_type = admin', ["%{$user_name}%"])
```

Which gives me an error:
**"Array to string conversion"**

I have also tried:

```
$users = User::whereRaw('lower(info_json->"$.full_name") like lower(?) and user_type = admin', ["%{$user_name}%"])
```

Which give me the following error:
**"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_type' in 'where clause'"**

Other similar variations that have not resulted in errors have yielded too many or too few results.

How can I successfully adjust my syntax to query an additional non-JSON field with the correct results? Also, is doing a raw query like this the most effective way to do so with Eloquent, MySQL (5.79) and Laravel 5.6?

Thank you for any and all help/direction offered!  :)

Comment: Does the `users` table have a `user_type` column?

Comment: Yes that is what I’d like to add an AND to my query for so I can narrow down my results further.

Comment: What's the executed SQL?

Comment: @Jonas Staudenmeir I did end up figuring the problem I had with my syntax out.  I was wondering though if for future reference you know of a tool that could be used to debug executed SQL using Eloquent?

Comment: You can use the debugbar: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  My syntax should have looked like this:

```
$users = User::whereRaw('lower(info_json->"$.full_name") like lower(?)', ["%{$user_name}%"])->where('user_type', '=', 'admin')->get();
```

Thanks to those who assisted with this!  Like a lot of syntax/coding problems, taking a little break from it helped me to figure it out quite quickly when I returned to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do something like

```
$users = User::where(DB::raw('lower(info_json->"$.full_name")', 'like', DB::raw('lower(%{$user_name}%)'))
->where('user_type', '=', 'admin')
```

Probably I have some sintax error but main idea is to use `DB::raw` to help you with your query.

Comment: yeah your syntax was off.  I think I figured this out.  I will add an answer to this for someones benefit in the future.